# Finding highway exits along the way

Tags: routes, tomtom

Using [TomTom's APIs](https://developer.tomtom.com), is it possible to request the highways exits along a calculated route?

Assume a route has been calculated using the [Routing API](https://developer.tomtom.com/routing-api/routing-api-documentation-routing/calculate-route), I would like to be able to get the highway exits (if any) within this route. Not the ones that I have to take, but any that I also might pass.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to achieve this because the Routing API doesn't provide that information, but you can build basic algorithm to solve it.

What comes to my mind: you can try to create two paths that are parallel to your route, select points on that paths every X kilometers and ask for a +route to each of them. Compare the response to the master route. Last point that is covered by both routes should indicate the exit.
But this solution is not very cost effective.

Comment: Thanks @szogoon. Yes there are brute force methods which are both computationally and monetarily inefficient. I was wondering if there is a proper way to do this (using the TomTom API) that I haven't been able to find in the documentation?

Comment: We discussed this with our engineers and unfortunately there is no straight solution.

Comment: Maybe you can add it to the "feature list" :) Thanks again